# Intellij Keyboard shortcut to bring terminal into focus without clicking on it?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a terminal open while writing some code and I want to be able to access it without having to drag my mouse to said terminal and clicking on it.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that would allow me to accomplish the desired behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You can see the default or assign a new shortcut in the IDE Keymap settings (File | Settings | Keymap):

[image: File | Settings | Keymap]

It's also possible to use the [Switcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html#switcher) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). While Holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button you can press the mnemonic on the left to activate the corresponding tool window (<kbd>T</kbd> for the Terminal).

[image: switcher]

Answer (score 0):

Default keybind on Windows is : `t while holding ctrl + tab`

Answer (score 0):

Default <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> works fine for me. Any problems with it?